# not able to detect user id and put it in json file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
def addUpvoteRecord(userid):
  with open("vote.json") as f:
      vote_list = json.load(f)

  if not userid in vote_list:
      vote_list[userid] = []

  with open("vote.json", "w+") as f:
      json.dump(vote_list, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message) :

    if message.channel.id == 870147153706750022 :
        data = message.content.split(" ")
        user = re.sub("\D", "", data[5])
        addUpvoteRecord(user)
    
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

i am getting this error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

can anyone help me??

Comment: Can you please give more details such as which line the error is occurring in?

Comment: 6th line       vote_list[userid] = []

Comment: You're passing in `user` which is a string into your `userid` then using it as an indice in line 6. You need to use a number to get a certain item in a list. EG; `vote_list[1] = []`

Answer (score 0):

> 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

This means one of your list indices is a string, but python expected it to be an integer. I think your error occurred in this line `vote_list[userid] = []`. Try `vote_list[int(userid)] = []`.

Comment: ```
vote_list[int(userid)] = []
IndexError: list assignment index out of range```

i am entering this in the channel '475975102576590849 475975102576590849 475975102576590849 475975102576590849 475975102576590849 475975102576590849
'

Comment: Could you send me a part of your json file?